# Null foreign key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have a Database with different types of users. The users are going to be assigned to a location based on the user type. For example a sector user will have a SectorId and a community user will have a CommunityId. Now this means a Sector user will have Null as his/her CommunityId. Whats the best way to resolve this?

I have tried creating different tables for different types of users to get rid of these null columns but I feel it is not the best approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have too many columns, then your approach is fine.  You can set up `check` constraints to ensure data integrity.

From what you describe, I think the logic looks like:

```
create table t (
    . . .,
    sectorId int references sectors(sectorId),
    communityId int references communities(communityId),
    check ( ( (case when sectorId is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when sectorId is not null then 1 else 0 end)
            ) = 1  -- exactly one set
          ),
    check ( type = 'sector' and sectorId is not null or
            type = 'community' and communityId is not null
          )
);
```

These constraints check:

- That the columns refer to the correct tables.
- That only one of the id columns is set.
- That the id columns harmonize with the type column.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Can you please clarify what the checks are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by rather adding 2 tables (Location and LocationType). So every user has a LocationId instead.